# Android: How to force TextToSpeech to speak out the full stop "."

Tags: android, text, double, speech-to-text

I have used the text to speech service to narrate a double number in an edit text. I used a function to separate the digits composing that double to force the narrator to read digits individually. I know the separation function works well and the narrator speaks out all the digits but without pronouncing "point" for the full stop.

I know it should act this way as "." is a full stop but I believe there is a way to force it to speak it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could always insert a string containing "point" between the number and the decimal digits.

Comment: Ok, that might be so much convenient for this purpose. Can you provide a code to detect the point in a double so that enables me to replace it with "point"?